# How to share image as thumbnail using react share

Tags: reactjs, react-share

How to share my image from server as thumbnail in react share for facebook ,whatsapp, twitter etc..
I tried with react helmet but no use

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making negative value for my question ,kindly answer it first